How do I correctly collect the click, drag and release of a mouse event for CanvasView in SwiftUI on MacOS
For this drawing application on MacOS using SwiftUI and I'm having an interesting issue. The DragGesture does not trigger when I click inside my Canvas. It does trigger if I click on an item in my toolbar, or right panel. I have disabled every single view (Toolbars, Right Panel, Rulers, RulerGrid etc) and the problem still persists.
Simplified CanvasView looks like this:
GeometryReader { geometry in
    Path { path in
        for curObj in dm.objects {
            DrawingHelper.draw( curObj, in: geometry.size)
        }
    }
    .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
    .foregroundColor(.black)
    .allowsHitTesting(true)
    .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { value in
                currentPoints.append(value.location)
                print( "in onChanged")
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                print( "in onEnded")
                if currentPoints.count > 1 {
                    let newObject = DrawingObject(
                        tool: dm.curTool,
                        points: currentPoints,
                        ...
                )
                dm.drawingObjects.append(newObject)
            }
            currentPoints.removeAll()
        }
    )

Edit-1 - How the CanvasView is being called
GeometryReader { geometry in
    HStack (spacing: 0) {   // Remove space on right 
        Rulers( dm ) {
            ZStack {        // Draw rulerGrid on top
                CanvasView( dm ).background( .white )

                if( dm.showRulerGrid == true ) {
                    RulerGrid( dm ).background( .clear )
                }
            }
        } onRulerDoubleClick: { isShowingRulerSettings.toggle( )}
            .popover(isPresented: $isShowingRulerSettings, arrowEdge: .trailing) {
                RulerSettingsView( dm )
            }
            .background( .clear )
        
        if( dm.showPanel ) {
            RightPanelView( dm )
                .background( .black )
                .animation(.easeInOut( duration: 0.5) ) // TODO: Update this
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }   // End of Side Panel
        
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background( .clear )
}


What is CanvasView? Is it a view you have defined? Or do you mean Canvas?

CanvasView is something I defined I put the original code above inside the this Canvas View.  It doesn't have a lot of extra lines.  I hard code a Circle and Square into this view just thought it easier for discussion to not have that stuff in here.  I'll add how I call it above.

DrawingHelper.draw( curObj, in: geometry.size) doesn't take the path as a parameter, so how exactly does it draw anything? Also consider using Canvas instead of a simple Path. I think that might help.

I didn't give you the code for DrawingHelper... it does take the current object and it has the Circle, Square etc code in it.

A Path’s hit-testable area is, by default, its stroked or filled area. For a stroked path, that’s typically not a very big area—in your case, just a 2-point-wide line.
You probably want it to be the whole rectangle around the path:
Path { path in
        for curObj in dm.objects {
            DrawingHelper.draw( curObj, in: geometry.size)
        }
    }
    .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
    .foregroundColor(.black)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())        // <—- ADD THIS
    .gesture(
        ... etc


Woots that hit detection is definitely working in the Canvas view but the objects don't draw so maybe this hit detection should actually be on the ZStack or the Geometry.  I didn't think a contentShape would be required as it should be the entire Canvas.  At least that was my thought when I woke up this morning.  Gonna try that next.

I wasn't expecting that to work but it did TY.  I was expecting the current container to be used.  Even content shape doesn't include the size which is odd.  I'm now collecting the drawing detail lines, circles, squares but can't get things to draw.
